# How to link the title in a teaser to the main content?

Tags: views

I have created a view that provides teaser content for different nodes.

This teaser content carries a main title and some more fields. I want to make the title as a link, which when clicked, takes the user to a page that displays the full node.

I tried enabling the "Link this field to its entity" for the title field in its view, but clicking on that link takes me to a page like:

```
http://localhost:8082/node/<node id>
```

I want it to go to a prettier looking URL like:

```
http://localhost:8082/<pretty URL>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: my bad.. Looks like the formating was lost.. edited it back

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a node title field, then the "Link this field to its entity" option should definitely work.

By default it will link to

localhost:8082/node/123

where 123 is the node ID of the node.

If you want a nicer URL, like

localhost:8082/title

where title is the title of the node (or something similar), try the [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, which allows you to define settings that automatically create pretty urls for nodes (and users and taxonomy terms, etc.).
The pretty urls can use tokens, like [node:title], which will be replaced by the title of the node for example.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded and installed pathauto and i got the pretty urls working.

Comment: Now how can i tell drupal which "view mode" (either full content, teaser or custom) to display when the user clicks on this URL.

Comment: Because it is the full node page that is being linked to it will display the full content view mode. You can't change that. You can however change what the view mode displays. You can do this by going to admin/structure/types and then going to the manage display link for the content type you want to customise. There you can set which fields display and how they display for each view mode. Change the full content one to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The [PathAuto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, (already mentioned by rooby) will "prettify" URLs for you automatically.

If you *instead* wants to do this yourself, check out *Admin/Configuration/URL aliases*.  This let you create aliases by hand (such as "Title" for "node/123").